# how to write code in java 8 use Optionals

Tags: java, option-type

I have a code like this. How can it be rewritten more correctly?

```
Optional<String> getNameBySiiPriorityInfo(Optional<SiiPriorityInfo> siiPriorityInfo){
    return siiPriorityInfo.isPresent() ? Optional.ofNullable(siiPriorityInfo.get().getName()) : Optional.empty();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have an optional and you want to get another optional given by performing an operation on the object inside the optional, use [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-).

```
return siiPriorityInfo.map(SiiPriorityInfo::getName);
```